# Animate changes during device rotation based on size element will be after rotation completes

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, screen-rotation, size-classes

I have a dynamic setup of buttons that automatically adjust in width and height based on auto layout constraints set up in a storyboard. When in portrait the buttons have equal widths and heights so the frame is perfectly square, and when the device is rotated to landscape the buttons get shorter and wider. I have set `cornerRadius` on the buttons' layers so they're perfectly circular when in portrait and that works well, but when I rotate to landscape the corner radius doesn't look right anymore obviously. I need to change that so it becomes an oval. The problem is, no matter where I try to put that code, I cannot get the correct width and height the buttons will be after the rotation occurs. I want this to occur while the device is being rotated - don't want to wait until the rotation has completed. Ideally the `cornerRadius` would animate the change while the transition animates.

If I use `viewWillLayoutSubviews` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, it correctly gets the button frame when the app is launched, but upon rotating to landscape this method is called before the button's frame is updated for the new orientation, so I can't calculate the correct corner radius.

If I use `viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:` or `willTransitionToTraitCollection:withTransitionCoordinator:` or `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation`, it doesn't get called when the app is launched, and upon rotating the device it is called before the frame is updated for the new size.

If I use `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation`, it doesn't get called when the app is launched, but upon rotating the device it does correctly get the new button frame. But this method is deprecated.

**So the question is, what method can you use to set the properties of a button based on the size the button will be when rotation has completed, that is called before the rotation has completed?**

Note that it needs to be called for every orientation change, not just size class changes (rotating iPad doesn't change the size class). I only need to support iOS 8.0+.

This is the code I'm placing in the methods to know if it is getting the correct size:

```
println("\(button.frame.size.width) x \(button.frame.size.height)")
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Below I outline how one could use a `CADisplayLink` to update the properties during every frame of the animation, but there is an easier way. Subclass the button (or view or whatever) with a `layoutSubviews` that updates the corner radius:

```
class RoundedCornerView: UIView {

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        layer.cornerRadius = min(bounds.width, bounds.height) / 2
    }

}
```

Then, during the animation, as the frame size changes, the corner radius is updated automatically:

[image]

---

As Joey points out, one can use `viewWillTransitionToSize` to be notified of the new size, and then use `animateAlongsideTransition` to coordinate your additional animation along with the main animation.

If you want to animate an un-animatable property, such as corner radius (in block-based animations, anyway), you can use a display link for the duration of the animation. This effectively calls our method for every frame of the rotation animation. thus, we'll have a method that looks at the presentation layer (which shows you the current state of a layer mid-animation) to adjust the corner radius on the fly. You can use `animateAlongsideTransition` for this, too, but we're not using the `animation` closure in this case, but rather merely using the `completion` closure to know when the animation is done and therefore can stop the display link:

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransitionToSize(size, withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator)

    let displayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: "handleDisplayLink:")
    displayLink.addToRunLoop(NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop(), forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)

    coordinator.animateAlongsideTransition(nil) { (context) -> Void in
        displayLink.invalidate()
    }
}

func handleDisplayLink(displayLink: CADisplayLink) {
    updateButtonsCornerRadius()
}

func updateButtonsCornerRadius() {
    for button in [button1, button2] {
        let presentationLayer = button.layer.presentationLayer() as CALayer
        let minDimension = min(presentationLayer.frame.size.width, presentationLayer.frame.size.height)
        button.layer.cornerRadius = minDimension / 2.0
    }
}
```

Frankly, I'm not sure this corner radius animation is enough to justify this display link (I had to slow down animations in the simulator with <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to appreciate the difference), but this illustrates the basic idea.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is to use `viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:`, with your code placed inside the animation closure of `UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator`'s `animateAlongsideTransition:` method. This will allow you to animate the changes based on the size it will be when rotation completes.

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransitionToSize(size, withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator)

    coordinator.animateAlongsideTransition({ (context: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext!) -> Void in
        self.updateButtonsCornerRadius()
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

This method is not called when the app launches though so you'll want to call `self.updateButtonsCornerRadius()` in `viewDidLoad` as well.