# What method is called on UIView when it's resized by autolayout?

Tags: ios, uiview, resize, autolayout, frame

I have an image view that I'm implementing rounded corners on by overriding the following in my subclass:

```
-(void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame {
  [super setFrame:frame];
  [self.layout setCornerRadius:frame.size.width/10.0];
}
```

This works great for the initial display of the image, but if the size of the image changes due to device rotation or some other mechanism, this method does not get called to implement the resize.

I'm using autolayout, and I want to know what method of UIView (and thus UIImageView) is being called when my constraints resize the view so that I can recalculate my corner radius whenever this resize takes place. My (apparently false) assumption was that the autolayout system called `setFrame:` to move / resize views as needed.

Comment: Try putting this in `layoutSubviews`.

Comment: Putting it in layoutSubviews works! Thank you Rob. The only problem I see is that the change is abrupt instead of smoothly animated, which creates a "flicker" effect when the image is resized from large to small and vice-versa. 


I tried putting this in drawRect: to see if it give me a smooth animation of resizing corners, but it seems drawRect: isn't even being called (at least not in the simulator)!

Comment: Take a look at the UIView Class Reference:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816

There is a specific block named "Subclassing Notes" that may be very helpful for you.

Comment: When doing an animation that needs to be coordinated with a rotation, for example, you can use  `animateAlongsideTransition` with the transition coordinator. When animating something that cannot be animated with block based animation, you can combine that with display link:: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28259619/1271826

Comment: Good to know! I do agree with your comment in that thread, "Frankly, I'm not sure this corner radius animation is enough to justify this display link (I had to slow down animations in the simulator with command+T to appreciate the difference), but this illustrates the basic idea." I'll likely stick with your original suggestion to use layoutSubviews. Thanks again!

Comment: Seems like putting this code in the parent view's layoutSubviews might help the problem as well Michael.

Answer (score 7):

From the docs on `updateConstraints`:

> Custom views that set up constraints themselves should do so by overriding this method
>
> ....
>
> Before layout is performed, your implementation of updateConstraints will be invoked, allowing you to verify that all necessary constraints for your content are in place at a time when your custom view’s properties are not changing.

Or from the docs on `layoutSubviews`:

> You should override this method only if the autoresizing and constraint-based behaviors of the subviews do not offer the behavior you want. You can use your implementation to set the frame rectangles of your subviews directly.

but if you need to do this on rotational changes, check out  `willTransitionToTraitCollection:withTransitionCoordinator:`

> Implementors of this method can use it to adapt the interface based on the values in the newCollection parameter. A common use of this method is to make changes to the high-level presentation style when the current size class changes.