# iOS8 UIView width 320

Tags: ios, uiview, storyboard, constraints

There is the question: I set a custom view named ZHLockView. I put it in the storyboard and I set the constraints. But I can't get the correct width in `- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder`, it is always 320, what should I do to get the correct width?

Last I know in the `- (void)layoutSubviews`, I can get the right width, but it will going twice. Is there a better idea?

Comment: What do you mean by "the correct width"? What width do you expect? What constraints have you set?

Comment: The view won't have been laid out yet in `initWithCoder:`, so it will just have the frame that you gave it in the storyboard.  The best place to get the correct width would depend on what you are trying to do with it.

Comment: The main constraints is that  the width is equal to superView.width. I want to get the correct width in different devices

Comment: The view itself shouldn't be worrying about filling it's superview.  The superview should be adding those contraints when it adds your view as a subview.

Comment: @ZhiChang Check which iPhone Retina you selected in storyboard. and also check the width of Your view

Answer (score 0):

See, you're getting width 320 because your view is of that size on storyboard.

If the width of the view is equal to superview, which is indeed again equal to width of device, you can use following code to get width of view at anytime and dont need to worry about where to write.

**Swift** :-

```
CGFloat width  = CGRectGetWidth(UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds);
CGFloat height = CGRectGetHeight(UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds);
```

**Objective-C** :-

```
CGFloat width  = CGRectGetWidth([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]);
CGFloat height = CGRectGetHeight([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]);
```

Hope you understood and it helps you.. :)

Comment: Thanks, I know this. But if the superView's frame isn't the screen width?

Comment: Then, what is that you want to achieve in code? Please share the code.

Comment: Ok, I found a good answer here.. Have a look.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28501903/what-method-is-called-on-uiview-when-its-resized-by-autolayout        Hope that solves your issue. Let me know.. :)

Answer (score 0):

The view will be load with the value in the xib at the first start, next when the autolayout engine makes the first pass, it will be set to a new value according to the constraints set.
Why would you need to know the size? Autolayout is made to do not care about it.
`-layoutSubviews`, `-viewWillLayout`, `-viewDidLayout` are called when the layout engine needs a update, that could means Different times before displaying your view.

Comment: Because in the file of .m, I use some 'for' statements which is convenient than constraints

Comment: If you use autolayout, you MUST forget about changing frames manually, you should only changing constraints. Even if it seems to be working now, it should break between different minor releases of iOS

Answer (score 0):

the code is here

> objc

```
#define KScreenWidth [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width
CGFloat height = 0;
CGFloat margin = (KScreenWidth - columnCount * btnW) / (columnCount + 1);
for (int i = 0; i < btnCount; i++) {
    int row = i / columnCount;
    int column = i % columnCount;
    CGFloat btnX = margin + column * (btnW + margin);
    CGFloat btnY = row * (btnW + margin);
    height = btnH + btnY;
    ZHButtonView *button = [[ZHButtonView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(btnX, btnY, btnW, btnH)];
    button.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    button.currentIndex = i;
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"gesture_node_normal"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"gesture_node_highlighted"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [self addSubview:button];
}
```

Comment: OK, your code has no relation with view's frame. I think you can call it in viewDidLoad. It should work fine.